# If I wanted to create a ruby/rails gem to manage CSS class precedence, where would I start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, css, rubygems

This is what I want my gem to do...once included in a Rails gem file, it will allow the developer to specify which stylesheet is the main, and which is a 'secondary'. The idea being, that all the styles in the first stylesheet take precedence over all the others - but when a style does not exist in the main, it uses the ones in secondary.

For instance, if there is `body` in `main.css` and in `secondary.css`, it always uses the style from `main.css`. But if there is `alert-message` in `secondary.css`, but not in main, the developer can use `alert-message`, without any fear of conflicts.

The idea basically is to allow you to leverage existing frameworks or minified stylesheets that might have classes that clash with your `main.css` without having to worry that your entire site/app will be messed up.

It would be awesome if I could get a general overview of the entire Rails/Ruby gem creating process - as this would be my first. Then maybe some discussions about how I might go about solving this particular problem (from a high-level is fine).

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that it would require a lot of work. You'd have to extend (or write your own) CSS parser. Or come up with another way of specifying which classes are "main".

I think, the solution is **much** less complicated. Simply include your "main" stylesheet after all "secondaries". That'll overwrite the classes, if there are conflicts.

Comment: I tried that many times, in many different combinations and there are always conflicts. I don't know if there is something behind the scenes going on, but I have two separate `<% stylesheet_link_tag %>` calls for the two stylesheets I want, and no matter how I do it - some things render fine (i.e. from my `main.css`) and others render weird - because it's obvious their styles are clashing. I am trying to use Bootstrap from Twitter with my main, but I don't want to use every single style - that's where this comes from.

Comment: @marcamillion: well, good luck with that, but I would rename my classes if I were you :-)

Comment: I would, if the stylesheet wasn't 2000 lines long :(